# efficiently locf by groups in a single R data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, rcpp

I have a large, wide `data.table` (20m rows) keyed by a person ID but with lots of columns (~150) that have lots of null values.  Each column is a recorded state / attribute that I wish to carry forward for each person.  Each person may have anywhere from 10 to 10,000 observations and there are about 500,000 people in the set.  Values from one person can not 'bleed' into the following person, so my solution must respect the person ID column and group appropriately.

For demonstration purposes - here's a very small sample input:

```
DT = data.table(
  id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  aa=c("A", NA, "B", "C", NA, NA, "D", "E", "F", NA, NA, NA),
  bb=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  cc=c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 5, 6, NA, 7, NA)
)
```

It looks like this:

```
    id aa bb cc
 1:  1  A NA  1
 2:  1 NA NA NA
 3:  1  B NA NA
 4:  1  C NA NA
 5:  2 NA NA NA
 6:  2 NA NA  4
 7:  2  D NA NA
 8:  2  E NA  5
 9:  3  F NA  6
10:  3 NA NA NA
11:  3 NA NA  7
12:  3 NA NA NA
```

My expected output looks like this:

```
    id aa bb cc
 1:  1  A NA  1
 2:  1  A NA  1
 3:  1  B NA  1
 4:  1  C NA  1
 5:  2 NA NA NA
 6:  2 NA NA  4
 7:  2  D NA  4
 8:  2  E NA  5
 9:  3  F NA  6
10:  3  F NA  6
11:  3  F NA  7
12:  3  F NA  7
```

I've found a `data.table` solution that works, but it's terribly slow on my large data sets:

```
DT[, na.locf(.SD, na.rm=FALSE), by=id]
```

I've found equivalent solutions using dplyr that are equally slow.

```
GRP = DT %>% group_by(id)
data.table(GRP %>% mutate_each(funs(blah=na.locf(., na.rm=FALSE))))
```

I was hopeful that I could come up with a rolling 'self' join using the `data.table` functionality, but I just can't seem to get it right (I suspect I would need to use `.N` but I just haven't figured it out).

At this point I'm thinking I'll have to write something in Rcpp to efficiently apply the grouped locf.

I'm new to R, but I'm not new to C++ - so I'm confident I can do it.  I just feel like there should be an efficient way to do this in R using `data.table`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `DT[, lapply(.SD, na.locf, F), by = id]` will be faster

Comment: I actually started with that and found the performance to be worse.

Comment: Rolling self join looks to be on point here, I remember some questions that have both `na.locf` and rolling joins answers, so I think you may find the answer in current SO knowledge base.

Comment: With an ordered "id", perhaps you could use something like: `tmp = c(TRUE, DT$id[-1] != DT$id[-nrow(DT)]); DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[cummax(((!is.na(x)) | tmp) * seq_len(nrow(DT)))])]`?

Comment: @alexis_laz - wow!  That's amazing!  It works and it's 2 full orders of magnitude faster than the data.table solution.  Can you help me understand what the code is doing?  Also, your comment should be made into an answer so I can mark this solved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A very simple `na.locf` can be built by forwarding (`cummax`) the non-`NA` indices (`(!is.na(x)) * seq_along(x)`) and subsetting accordingly:

```
x = c(1, NA, NA, 6, 4, 5, 4, NA, NA, 2)
x[cummax((!is.na(x)) * seq_along(x))]
# [1] 1 1 1 6 4 5 4 4 4 2
```

This replicates `na.locf` with an `na.rm = TRUE` argument, to get `na.rm = FALSE` behavior we simply need to make sure the first element in the `cummax` is `TRUE`:

```
x = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 2)
x[cummax(c(TRUE, tail((!is.na(x)) * seq_along(x), -1)))]
#[1] NA NA  1  1  2
```

In this case, we need to take into account not only the non-`NA` indices but, also, of the indices where the (ordered, or to be ordered) "id" column changes value:

```
id = c(10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13)
c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-length(id)])
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Combining the above:

```
id = c(10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13)
x =  c(1,  NA, NA, 6,  4,  5,  4,  NA, NA, 2)

x[cummax(((!is.na(x)) | c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-length(id)])) * seq_along(x))]
# [1]  1  1 NA  6  4  5  4  4 NA  2
```

Note, that here we `OR` the first element with `TRUE`, i.e. make it equal to `TRUE`, thus getting the `na.rm = FALSE` behavior.

And for this example:

```
id_change = DT[, c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-.N])]
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[cummax(((!is.na(x)) | id_change) * .I)])]
#    id aa bb cc
# 1:  1  A NA  1
# 2:  1  A NA  1
# 3:  1  B NA  1
# 4:  1  C NA  1
# 5:  2 NA NA NA
# 6:  2 NA NA  4
# 7:  2  D NA  4
# 8:  2  E NA  5
# 9:  3  F NA  6
#10:  3  F NA  6
#11:  3  F NA  7
#12:  3  F NA  7
```

Comment: the downvote is very much not obvious to me, and some explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Great answer imo - not only is this a much faster version of a regular `na.locf`, but it also adds a modification to do it per group (assuming sorted groups), **without** actually doing a `by` loop (which would introduce extra `eval`'s per group and would slow it down). Unless I'm missing something - this should be the standard `na.locf` implementation, instead of the `rle` stuff that `zoo` does.

Comment: @eddi : thanks for the edits. I guess the `zoo::na.locf` is more flexible, though, I believe that for simple cases, the `4-5 * length(x)` scans of the `cummax` version shall be pretty straightforward. And, also, it indeed proved convenient to pass each column pointer once in the function and be applied virtually "by" group.

Comment: I might add that with my original test set of 20m rows, the first suggested `lapply` solution took 40 hours to complete.  The new code takes just 4 minutes!  I doubt Rcpp could do much better than that.

Comment: @carl.anderson I did a quick back of the envelope test, and you'll easily get 2-3x improvement with Rcpp

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes, imo. This answer has shaved off so much time from some of my processes. Thank you!!

Comment: This is an incredible solution! zoo::na.locf was the main bottleneck in my script!

Comment: zoo::na.locf work incorrectly ```zoo::na.locf(c(NA,1))``` will produce "1" instead of c(NA,1). Also, ```zoo::na.locf(c(NA))``` fail to "logical(0)" answer. ```na.locf``` can't be used.