# efficiently locf by groups in a single R data.table - FromLast

Tags: r, data.table, locf

I am wondering how to efficiently locf by groups in a single R data.table from the last, i.e. filling in NA values backward from the last know value.

There is a code [efficiently locf by groups in a single R data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060211/efficiently-locf-by-groups-in-a-single-r-data-table) for forward direction but I am looking for the opposite direction. Any idea how to adjust the code?

Comment: For numeric values you could use `data.table::nafilll(...,type='nocb')`

Comment: See `help("nafill")` and combine that with data.table's `by`. You can be more efficient if your data fulfills additional conditions. E.g., I'm working with data right now, where the last value of each group is guaranteed to be non-NA. That means I can just sort the data.table by group-ID and time and then simply use `setnafill`.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it is pretty slow for large data compared to the code I referred to.
However, I found a workaround: I sorted the data reversely, applied the code in the link and sorted the data back again. It made the trick, but I am wondering whether exists more efficient way without the two extra sorting steps.

Comment: By the code I mean:

`id_change = DT[, c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-.N])]
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[cummax(((!is.na(x)) | id_change) * .I)])]`

Answer (score 0):

A bit workaround, but anyway:
first, sort data reversely, apply the code to replace the NAs, sort back.

```
DT <- arrange(DT, desc(id))
id_change = DT[, c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-.N])] 
DT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[cummax(((!is.na(x)) | id_change) * .I)])]
DT <- arrange(DT, id)
```